# regex match all `,` not inside \[\]

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the example string which I have to match:

```
   var sampleStr = "aaa[bbb=55,zzz=ddd],#ddd[ppp=33,kk=77,rr=fff],tt,ff";
```

I need to write regex that will match all `,` characters which is not inside `[` `]`

so In my sample string I should receive the next `,` characters:

```
   - `,` before `#ddd`
   - `,` before `tt`
   - `,` before `ff`
```

and it should ignore next `,`:

```
  - `,` before `zzz`
  - `,` before `kk`
  - `,` before `rr`
```

Actually I have no idea how to ignore those `,` inside `[...]`.
Big thx for any advance

Comment: `"aaa[bbb=55,zzz=ddd],#ddd[ppp=33,kk=77,rr=fff],tt,ff".split(/,(?![^\[\]]*\])/)` or `"aaa[bbb=55,zzz=ddd],#ddd[ppp=33,kk=77,rr=fff],tt,ff".match(/[^\[\],]+(\[[^\[\]]+\])?(?=,|$)/g)`. Both are brittle in edge cases, though.

Comment: Thank you! add it as answer and I will approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can assume that the part inside `[]` doesn't contain nested `[]`, and the `[]` are balanced:

```
var out = content.split(/,(?![^\[\]]*\])/);
```

`(?![^\[\]]*\])` is a negative look-ahead which checks that we are not inside `[]` with a heuristic. As long as we don't encounter any `]` as we consume characters other than `[` and `]`, then we are outside `[]`.

The code above will split the text along those commas `,` outside brackets `[]` and return the tokens.

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid commas enclosed in square brackets is to match square brackets first. Example for a replacement:

```
var result = sampleStr.replace(/([^\[,]*(?:\[[^\]]*\][^\[,]*)*),/g, '$1#');
```

Other example if you want to split:

```
var result = sampleStr.match(/(?=[^,])[^\[,]*(?:\[[^\]]*\][^\[,]*)*/g);
```

The advantage of these approaches is that you don't need to parse all the string until the end with a lookahead for each comma.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work

```
,(?![^\[]*?\])
```

see: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eU1dY2/1)

**Explanation**

`,` is our target comma,

`(?![^\[]*?\])` use negative lookahead to guarantee that there is no `]` after `,`, a trick here is instead of using `.*` we use `[^\[]*` to prevent regex match a pattern `[...]` instead of `..]`.